# React Native Sort Dictionary Based on Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, dictionary, filtering

I have a "reference" array that contains

`[“Push”,”Pull, “Leg”]`

and an array of dicts that looks like

```
{
    "bodyPart": "upper arms",
    "target": "biceps",
    "broad_target": "biceps",
    "ppl": "pull"
  },

{
    "bodyPart": "chest",
    "target": "pectorals",
    "broad_target": "chest",
    "ppl": "push"
  },
 
 {
    "bodyPart": "lower legs",
    "target": "calves",
    "broad_target": "legs",
    "ppl": "legs"
  },
```

I want the array to be sorted based on the PPL attribute based on the reference array.

So since the reference array is `push, pull, leg`, the array of dicts should look like

```
{
    "bodyPart": "chest",
    "target": "pectorals",
    "broad_target": "chest",
    "ppl": "push"
  },
{
    "bodyPart": "upper arms",
    "target": "biceps",
    "broad_target": "biceps",
    "ppl": "pull"
  },
 
 {
    "bodyPart": "lower legs",
    "target": "calves",
    "broad_target": "legs",
    "ppl": "legs"
  },
```

Comment: I've got many ideas on how you can implement this, but first of all... this "reference" array can change or it's always the same?

Comment: @LukaCerrutti, the reference array is based on previous user interactions, so we cannot "hard-code" a ```push/ pull/ leg```, but we can assume for this example that it will be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript `sort` function based on the index of the `ppl` attribute on the reference array (you can get this index using function `indexOf`). Here it is as a cute one-liner:

```
// Reference array
const arrRef = ["Push", "Pull", "Leg"];

// Dictionary array (order "Push - Leg - Push")
const arrDicts = [
    { "ppl": "Push" },
    { "ppl": "Leg" },
    { "ppl": "Push" },
];

// Sorting (should be "Push - Push - Leg")
arrDicts.sort((a, b) => arrRef.indexOf(a.ppl) - arrRef.indexOf(b.ppl));
```

EDIT: Adding the old proposed solution (back up array)

```
const arrRef = ["Push", "Pull", "Leg"];

const arrDicts = [
    {
        "bodyPart": "upper arms",
        "target": "biceps",
        "broad_target": "biceps",
        "ppl": "Push"
    },

    {
        "bodyPart": "chest",
        "target": "pectorals",
        "broad_target": "chest",
        "ppl": "Pull"
    },

    {
        "bodyPart": "lower legs",
        "target": "calves",
        "broad_target": "legs",
        "ppl": "Leg"
    },
];

// Create a back up array and iterate on the reference array, filtering the actual dicitionary array with `ppl == current reference`
const backupArr = [];
for (const ref of arrRef) 
    backupArr.push(...arrDicts.filter(x => x.ppl == ref))

// Now backupArr is ordered as you want to
console.log(backupArr)
```

*Please take in consideration this way of sorting the array will not include objects of the dictionary array that have a `ppl` attribute that is not in the reference array.*

Comment: I actually liked your previous one more. I believe this works well, but the 'back-up array' works better in my case. If you still have the previous code, please add it to this solution and I will approve it!

Comment: There, added 